# SQLAlchemy - Passing a list of Column to Table constructor

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I predefine a list of Column objects that I want to pass to the Table constructor

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine as sqla_create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table as sqla_Table
from sqlalchemy import Column as sqla_Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer as sqla_Integer
from sqlalchemy import String as sqla_String
from sqlalchemy import MetaData as sqla_MetaData


myColsX = [sqla_Column("id", sqla_Integer, primary_key=True),
               sqla_Column('namex', sqla_String(15)),
               sqla_Column('comment', sqla_String(120))]
```

If I call the Table constructor, with each Column instance, -- no problem:

```
myTable = sqla_Table(myTableNameX, myMetaData, 
                        sqla_Column("id", sqla_Integer, primary_key=True),
                        sqla_Column('namex', sqla_String(15)),
                        sqla_Column('comment', sqla_String(120)),
                        extend_existing=True)
myMetaData.create_all(myEngine, tables=[myTable], checkfirst=True)
```

...and I can call the Table construct multiple times with interleaving DROP table calls.

If on the other hand I pass the list of Column as:

```
myTable = sqla_Table(myTableNameX, myMetaData, *myColsX, 
                        extend_existing=True)
```

The Table is created the first time, but with a subsequent call following a DROP command

I get an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column object 'id' already assigned to Table 'tableX
```

Note also that I have tried various combinations of the Table flags: eg autoload=True, extend_existing=True, etc.

What is the correct way to create and pass the list of Column to the Table constructor?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just wrap the column list in a factory function and get a fresh set of columns each time, but I think this is an XY problem. Why do you want to regenerate the table definition in the metadata at all after a `DROP`? If the table has no changes, you can use the existing metadata to recreate it. If you need to add columns, use for example [`Table.append_column()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.append_column) against the existing `Table` metadata.

Comment: I am running my wrapper methods in python unittest. ...but I can envision cases where one creates a table, uses it... drops it.. and then starts with a fresh, recreated table. Note however I think that the root problem is related to passing the Column list as a *arg vs explicitly passing each Column.

myCols = [ Column(), Column(), Column()]
Table(.., ..., *myCols)

vs

Table(.., ...., Column(), Column(), Column())    <-- this works just fine

Comment: This is a good time to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, in the former the list holds references to the `Column` objects, while in the latter you create the objects and pass a reference to them directly in the call, never storing another reference to them. About the envisioned case, it'd still not require you recreating the table metadata. Just use the existing `Table` to recreate it in the database. The thing is that `Table` is just a description of sorts (metadata) of a table that maybe exists in your database. It is not bound to the actual table in the database.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to create a deepcopy of the list of Column objects before using it. Something like:

```
import copy

_myColsX = [sqla_Column("id", sqla_Integer, primary_key=True),
               sqla_Column('namex', sqla_String(15)),
               sqla_Column('comment', sqla_String(120))]

myColsX = copy.deepcopy(myColsX)
myTable = sqla_Table(myTableNameX, myMetaData, *myColsX, 
                        extend_existing=True)
```

In this way, references to the Column objects modified by calls to sqla_Table(which modifies internal Columns link table=None to table=myTableNameX) are not kept on subsequent calls of the same module.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Ilja Everilä's comments about names, references, etc I switched to instantiating the Table/Columns in the unittest setup() method. In this way I was not reusing the objects that I was trying to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ilja Everilä's suggestion of a factory.  `sqlalchemy.Column` objects mutate when assigned to a table, which can cause various bugs.  A similar case, common in configuring default `logging.Logger`s, is if you have a function to create/access a table based upon a name passed as an argument, but you know the table has a standard schema, stored in a global constant.

To implement a factory, in place of defining the name `myColsX` try:

```py
def get_myColsX():
    return [
        sqla_Column("id", sqla_Integer, primary_key=True),
        sqla_Column('namex', sqla_String(15)),
        sqla_Column('comment', sqla_String(120))
    ]
```

Then later, you can create the table with:

```py
myTable = sqla_Table(myTableNameX, myMetaData, *get_myColsX(), 
                        extend_existing=True)
```

And subsequent calls to drop should work.